# DVB-T sound in VLC is jittering

Tags: 11.04, sound, vlc, dvb

After upgrading to Natty sound is jittering in VLC when watching DVB-T. About every 5 seconds the sounds stops for milliseconds, which is annoying. DVB-T sound works fine in MPlayer.

Probably this is a bug in VLC. How to get this fixed in Natty?

Comment: I'd recommend you just use MPlayer - I found VLC buggy on both Windows and Ubuntu, unlike MP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) with the VLC 1.0.6 Goldeneye.
Every now and then (from several seconds to a dozen or so) there were short but annoying sound jitters / clicks / cracks when watching DVB-T.

The following change of VLC settings solved it.

Open "Tools" -> "Preferences" ("Ctrl+P"), click "Show Settings" -> "All", find "Input / Codecs" -> "Access modules" -> "DVB" ("DVB input with v4l2 support"), increase "Caching value in ms" from the default value of 300 to something like 1000.

Comment: i wonder if this is "fixed" in the newest version or maybe filed as a bug ... cheers